# How do give a specific mode to all directories and another to all files in a spec file?

Tags: permissions, installation, rpm

I can't rely on the umask since my machine does not use umask to set permissions. Is there a way to specify that all sub-directories (and their sub-directories etc) of some root directory all have a certain permission, and similarly, that all sub-files of the same root directory have another type of permission in the %files section of the spec file.

If not, I'll have to run some external bash scrip to get the spec file syntax for each individual file, and copy that output to the %files section of the spec file, which will be highly tedious.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [various references online](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-specref-files-list-directives.html), `%defattr()` takes a lesser-known fourth parameter for directories.